# How create a CASE INSENSITIVE database also using latin characteres?

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm using Firebird 2.5 and I was searching about create a database that supports case insensitive. I was successfully in this point using the UTF8 charset together with UNICODE_CI_AI Collate, the problem now is that this configuration doesn't support latin accentuation such as: "Ã Ó Ç À" etc... For latin accentuation I was using ISO8859_1 but this does'nt work with case insensitive.

So how can I solve this? I need a database that supports both, case insensitive and latin accentuation.

EDIT: This is my database/table config:

[image]

And this is what I got when I try to insert the word 'PÃO' for example:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't support latin accentuation" ? Unicode has those characters, doesn't it ?

Comment: you can create new collation - https://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-ddl-collation.html /// And you can use existing collation - https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-collations.html

Comment: I agree with Arioch 'The: What do you mean with _"this configuration doesn't support latin accentuation"_. Unicode supports all known characters, including those 'latin' characters.

Comment: Hello! I made an update on my post with more information about what happens when I try to insert a word with portuguese character. Please give a look.

Comment: What is EXACTLY Firebird and IBExpert versions you use? What is database's ODS ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you use FB 2.5 and according to [the documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-appx06-charsets.html) you have three collations for Unicode:

- UNICODE
- UNICODE_CI
- UNICODE_CI_AI

Is the middle one what you looked for?

If not, you can use `CREATE COLLATION` command to modify existing ones in the way you need. It is also documented by the link above, or in [a separate earlier document](https://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-ddl-collation.html).

## UPDATE

Okay, so I took my test old box with Firebird 2.1.7 and its database with ODS 11.1
And I find it having `UNICODE` and `UNICODE_CI` but not `UNICODE_CI_AI`
I could not create AI collation in FB 2.1 - despite documentation it kept complaining on "accent" token or collation attributes.

I opened the same DB file using IBE's stock Firebird 2.5.1 Embedded

- C:\Program Files\IBExpert\IBEUDB\fbembed.dll

Then I run the following:

```
CREATE COLLATION UNICODE_CI_AI
FOR UTF8 FROM UNICODE_CI
   accent INSENSITIVE;

recreate table so_58758871 (
 f1 varchar(20) character set UTF8 collate UNICODE,
 f2 varchar(20) character set UTF8 collate UNICODE_CI,
 f3 varchar(20) character set UTF8 collate UNICODE_CI_AI
);


insert into so_58758871 values (
 :sensitive, :semisens, :insensitive
);
```

And it... just works, in Firebird 2.5.1 (old and bad version, but is shipped in IBE, so I did not bother) at least.

[image: storing characters]
[image: fetching characters]

Comment: Hello! I made an update on my post with more information about what happens when I try to insert a word with portuguese character. Please give a look.